# What is the preferred way in JSX to gracefully handle an undefined error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

so I've released a version of my app which users are using but I'm thinking about deploying a potentially breaking change

currently something in the database is stored as a string but in my new release it'll be stored as an object

somewhere in the new JSX I do this: `person.name.split(' ')[0]` to get the first name. however, during my testing this is breaking as obviously that can't be done. `undefined is not an object` is the error message. so I was hoping to be able to handle this gracefully for old users until they make changes for the new way

I was hoping to do something like this: `{person.name.split(' ')[0] || fallback}` but this still breaks.

I guess I could `{person.name ? person.name.split(' ')[0] : fallback}` but I was just wondering if there was any nice pattern/preferred/standard way of doing this?

Comment: Can't speak for convention, but I personally use the ternary quite often. It could happen that person is undefined though, and then you have the same problem. I've created a utility function that I commonly use that will traverse an object and either return the property I'm looking for or a fallback. Something like `findProp(obj, ['traversal','path'], fallback)`. In this case it'd be `findProp(person, 'name', '').split(' ')[0]`. My traversal path takes a string or array.

Comment: I guess not really, at least i don't know a better way of doing it. If statements / ternary operator is the way to go for the most part. However, you can add an errorboundary wrapping component with a componentDidCatch hook, depending on the use case.